# CSS div header width don’t show 100%.

Tags: css, html

If I large my browser then my div header width don’t show 100%. But I set my div header width 100%. Please can someone point out what I may be doing wrong here? Many thanks. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome Page</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/icon.ico" >
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="style/login.css" type="text/css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="header">
            <div id="header_contain">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" style="font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold">Hello</td>
                        <td width="50%" align="right" style="font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold">What's Up!</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

css code

```
body
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:10pt;
}

#header
{
width: 100%;
height: 85px;
background: #006666;
}

#header_contain
{
    color: white;
    width: 980px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: working fine for me, did you try to change the browser?

Comment: Code works fine... all block level elements stretch to 100% width by default, you don't even need to set width: 100% for this to work correctly.

Comment: Supplied code alreadys works as expected. Maybe some other functionality needed?

Comment: I use firefox latest version. Actually I want to create two divs,first the one that streches for 100% and then inside put another one and set its width to 980px Thanks for yours replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use same color on header_contain div that I have already used in head div and this way I solve this problem.

```
#header
{
width: 100%;
height: 85px;
background: #006666;
}

#header_contain
{
    color: white;
    width: 980px;
height: 85px;
background: #006666;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set every element above the `<div>` to 100% width, including the `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my code and its tested.

1. HTML Code:

   ```
   <div id="header" style="width:1500px;">
           <div id="header_contain" style="min-width:980px;">

               <table>
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           <div style="width:500px;">
                           Hie, Div1 Content Here.!!
                           </div>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <div style="width:500px;">
                           Hie, Div2 Content Here.!!
                           </div>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                            <div style="width:500px;">
                           Hie, Div3 Content Here.!!
                           </div>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
              </table>

           </div>

           </div>
   ```
2. CSS Code..something like this.

   ```
   html, body
   {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10pt;
    overflow:auto;
   }

   #header
   {
    height: 85px;
    background: #006666;
   }

   #header_contain
   {
   color: white;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0px auto;
   padding-top: 30px;
   }
   ```

If It will helps you then don't forget to improve your accept rates. Cheers. !!

Comment: I use your code but If I stretch upto 100% then scrolling bar don't show. Actually I want to create a header like facebook. Facebook header colo div is 100% but facebook name and other information are set on 980px div.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header
width: 100%;
height: 85px;
background: #006666;
position:fixed;
z-index:999;
top:0;}
```